# concatenate many csvs, separated by a blank row, into a single csv

Tags: python, csv

I have this code that concatenate many csvs from a folder to a single csv file, but I would like that the concatenated csvs to be separated by a blank row in the final csv (finaloutput.csv). Any ideas? thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import pandas as pd
import glob, os
import shutil


path = r'/Users/sonia/PaleoSkull/Animalsmanage/output'

allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()  
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `csv` module to write the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()  
                outfile.write(b'\n')   # add a newline
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: It worked, although I had to change `bytearray ('\ n')` for `b'\ n'` because it gave me problems in Python 3.x.

Comment: Right. Corrected.